# Mysql query to group names then divide stats then display in order?

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I have a database like this:

```
USER   WL

Kevin  yes
Kevin  no
Kevin  yes
Steve  yes
Steve  no
```

I need to work out the amount of yes(Kevin has 2) and divide by total (Kevin has 3 in total) then display results in order of highest. Kevin 2 / 3 = 66%

```
SELECT *, SUM(wl = 'yes')/COUNT(wl) AS total
FROM Table1
WHERE user = '*' GROUP BY user ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called conditional counting. You can achive it by sum() or count(). I'll provide you with a sample query using sum():

```
SELECT user, SUM(if(wl = 'yes',1,0))/COUNT(wl) AS total
FROM Table1
GROUP BY user ORDER BY total DESC;
```

You can use case statement instead of if() function within the sum() as well.

Comment: I don't seem to get the right percentage for the user i need total YES divided by all for each user. I think its doing divided by all user and not each.

Comment: Pls provide meaningful feedback. What query do you exactly run, on what data, what is the expected output and what do you get.

Comment: So say the table above when i run the query i get a total of  0.6% as it's adding up all of WL and it's not grouping them under per USER so Kevin should be 0.66%. So its doing 2 / 5 and not 2 / 3

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about! The query contains a group by user clause, so the results are calculated by user. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27aba/1

Comment: 2/6 would yield 0.3333, not 0.6667.

Comment: You may apply some kind of rounding when you display the results.

Comment: If i put SUM(if(wl = 'yes',1,0))/COUNT(1) it comes back with the same problem so COUNT is not doing what i need. And not counting each users WL?

Comment: Sorry i think it's my maths lmao thank for the help dude ;-)